# Display a message for a deactivated link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a navigation bar with many links. The problem is that I am not done with all the pages. Is there anyway that I can block my users from clicking on certain links and instead display a little message that notifies them that the content will be coming soon?

Edit: It did not allow me to include bootstrap within the tags--but if a solution includes bootstrap, I am comfortable with it.

Edit 2: I have some jQuery effects on the navigation bar, is there anyway to also disable these effects when the link is clicked?

Comment: `<a href="#" title="Coming Soon!!!" class="inactive">Link</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you can use `href="#"` and alert message `onclick`:

```
<a href="#" onclick="alert('Under construction!')">MenuName</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a class to your links which are not ready. For i.e. `inactive` class. And then in jQuery you can simply do it like below:

```
$( ".inactive" ).click(function(event) {
   alert("This page is coming soon!");
   event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use alert for displaying message :

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="inactive">Link</a> 
<a href="#">Link Wroking</a>
```

JS

```
$('a.inactive').click(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();    
    var yesno = alert("Coming Soon");
});
```

Add class `inactive` for showing message. For the link which are working, don't add class `inactive`.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/972625jp/1/).